# Pandas ValueError when calling apply with axis=1 and setting lists of varying length as cell-value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, apply

While calling `apply` on a Pandas dataframe with `axis=1`, getting `ValueError` when trying to set a list as cell-value.

**Note**: Lists in different rows are of varying lengths and this seems to be cause, but not sure how to overcome it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [{'a': 1, 'b': '3412', 'c': 0}, {'a': 88, 'b': '56\t23', 'c': 1}, 
{'a': 45, 'b': '412\t34\t324', 'c': 2}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print("df: ")
print(df)

def get_rank_array(ids):
    ids = list(map(int, ids))
    return np.random.randint(0, 10, len(ids))

def get_rank_list(ids):
    ids = list(map(int, ids))
    return np.random.randint(0, 10, len(ids)).tolist()

df['rank'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_rank_array(row['b'].split('\t')), axis=1)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (3)

df['rank'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_rank_list(row['b'].split('\t')), axis=1)
print("df: ")
print(df)

df: 
    a             b  c       rank
0   1          3412  0        [6]
1  88        56\t23  1     [0, 0]
2  45  412\t34\t324  2  [3, 3, 6]
```

`get_rank_list` works but not `get_rank_array` in producing the above expected result.

I understand the (3,) shape comes from the number of columns in the dataframe, and (2,) is from the length of the list after splitting `56\t23` in the second row.
But I do not get the reason behind the error itself.

When

```
data = [{'a': 45, 'b': '412\t34\t324', 'c': 2}, 
{'a': 1, 'b': '3412', 'c': 0}, {'a': 88, 'b': '56\t23', 'c': 1}]
```

the error occurs with lists too.

Comment: Yes, this is because what you return has an incompatible shape with `df`. Please tell me what you're expecting back as your output, or if you know what you want?

Comment: Edited post to include expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe -

```
df.apply(lambda x: [0, 1, 2])

   a  b  c
0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2

df.apply(lambda x: [0, 1])

a    [0, 1]
b    [0, 1]
c    [0, 1]
dtype: object
```

Pandas does two things inside `apply`:

1. it special cases `np.array`s and `list`s, and
2. it attempts to snap the results into a DataFrame if the shape is compatible

Note that arrays are special cased a little differently to lists, in that, if the shape is not compatible, for lists, the result is a series (as you see in the second output above), but for arrays,

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.array([0, 1, 2]))

   a  b  c
0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2

df.apply(lambda x: np.array([0, 1]))
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 2), indices imply (3, 3)
```

In short, this is a consequence of the pandas internals. For more information, peruse the [`apply` function code on GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/36dadd70376c6033037af281a4669a360fc71cfa/pandas/core/frame.py#L4707-L4708).

---

To get your desired o/p, use a list comprehension and assign the result to `df['new']`. Don't use apply.

```
df['new'] = [
    np.random.randint(0, 10, len(x.split('\t'))).tolist() for x in df.b
]

df
    a             b  c        new
0   1          3412  0        [8]
1  88        56\t23  1     [4, 2]
2  45  412\t34\t324  2  [9, 0, 3]
```

Comment: In my actual code, I have `lists` and I still get the `ValueError`. Added additional example to post, so it is still not quite clear to me.

Also, how do I achieve the desired result then?

Comment: The actual operation I am doing is not just random number assignment, but involving all the columns of the row, which is why I was using `apply`. I wasn't aware of these consequences either.
But I suppose I could now do it as you suggested.

Then I will have to use `iterrows` or `itertuples` in place of just `df.b`. Should that be okay (also in terms of performance)?

Comment: @swathis It depends. It generally is alright for manageable amounts of data.